# Collective word for food and drink

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms

Is there a word that best describes food and drink taken at the same time? I've thought of *refreshments* and *consumables* but neither seem right to me.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

*[Sustenance](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/sustenance)* refers to *food and drink*.

Comment: in American Heritage Dictionary: 2. The supporting of life or health; maintenance: "to deliver in every morning six beeves, forty sheep, and other victuals for my sustenance" (Jonathan Swift)

Comment: @ScottBrown You might say, this answer "sustains" you! ;) :P :) :D :S

Answer (score 30):

*Victuals* might at a pinch be extended to include drink as well as food.

Answer (score 23):

"Victuals" is the correct word for food and drink; or you can use the old English form of the word "vittles".  Drink or beverages alone are sometimes referred to as "libations".

Answer (score 20):

According to US Legal, [aliments](http://definitions.uslegal.com/a/aliments/) are *food or drinks that can provide nourishment and support life.*

Apparently in the legal context they *may also include clothing*, but this was news to me.

Comment: Unfortunately if you actually used that word most people would assume you have misspelled ailments.

Comment: *Aliments* has been declining over a couple of centuries, and it's certainly dated, but I'd hardly say it's obsolete. Maybe it's more familiar to me because I know it in French, but *alimentation* seems like a pretty ordinary word I'd expect competent speakers to know - if only because they were taught about the *alimentary canal/tract/system* in biology. And thinking about it, if I asked for *aliments* in French, I'd expect drink as well as food (though I'd never expect to be offered clothing!).

Comment: To me, the first thing I think of is the alimentary canal. And since there's only a few situations where I'm likely to think about my alimentary canal that in turn leads me to think, well, let's say "food poisoning".

Comment: Steve314: The French would be insulted. They pride themselves on their *haute cuisine*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers If you happened to be nude while asking for aliments, would your expectations change?

Comment: @onomatomaniak: Trying to imagine the context, I suppose I might be expecting oysters, champagne, and maybe some erotic lingerie wrapped around an attractive young lady - but most likely it would turn out to be a dream anyway, and I'd wake up to find I was chewing my pillow! :)

Answer (score 12):

In my opinion, it depends on what other things you might want to connote.  For example, *refreshments* is a great word for food and drink together - especially food and drink at group functions like meetings and parties.

> "I look forward to seeing you at the all-hands meeting.  Don't forget that refreshments will be provided."

If you are talking about procuring food and drink together, you might call them *groceries*.

*Victuals* and *vittles* are also correct, but are not used in American vernacular (at least not on the east coast).

Answer (score 8):

I'm a bit surprised that *nourishment* hasn't come up as an answer itself, although it was used in the definition of another word...

> nour·ish·ment/ˈnəriSHmənt/ Noun:
>
> 1. The substances necessary for growth, health, and good condition.
> 2. Food.

The first definition would seem to include drink as well as food.

Answer (score 5):

[Fare](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%20fare&rls=com.microsoft%3aen-gb%3aIE-SearchBox&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=ie7&rlz=1I7ADFA_enGB440&redir_esc=&ei=xQXOTruHG8HAhAfb7OCqDQ#hl=en&rls=com.microsoft%3aen-gb%3aIE-SearchBox&rlz=1I7ADFA_enGB440&q=fare&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=xQXOTpawIIqYhQfwv_HKBg&ved=0CB0QkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=30879d0b5961a47b&biw=1280&bih=671) - the food and drink that are regularly served or consumed

Answer (score 5):

I've always liked "comestibles" though there may be a discussion as to whether this includes drinks or not, but then the boundary between food and drink can be a bit fuzzy.

Answer (score 3):

While we're coming up with slightly archaic terms, "provender" is listed in some places as meaning "food" but in others as being a synonym for "provisions".

Answer (score 2):

Is not "meal" appropriate that includes the process of eating and drinking?

Comment: Yesterday I went to the store and bought meal for the week.  ???

Comment: "meals for the week" sounds fine, but agreed this may not be ideal for all contexts

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm, on the vernacular front, I would propose CHOW, GRUB or FARE.

Answer (score 2):

For any fans of internet culture, the answer is clearly **Noms**, popularized by sites like icanhazcheeseburger.com (LOLCats), wins.failblog.org and others.

I was surprised that it didn't have widespread use outside of the internet - until I picked up my kids from daycare and the carer said "they've been good today - they had all their *noms*"

Comment: I am an occasional Failblog reader. *Noms*? I guess I need to read the words, not merely look at the pictures. That doesn't sound even vaguely familiar to me.

Answer (score 1):

Although "food and drink" is an accepted phrase, technically at least, there is no reason why drink should not be considered as food -- think "liquid foods". That way, I find *food* a sufficient word for all things that go into the alimentary canal for nutritional purposes, in whatever solid, liquid, gaseous (or plasma?) state.

I think for some living beings, their food consists exclusively of liquids. Some elderly people live on liquids alone.

So why not just say *food* where there is no ambiguity and *food and drink* where absolutely necessary?

Answer (score 0):

You can use *wherewithal* or *nourishment*.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the word *edibles*.

Comment: *edibles* is defined as "fit to be eaten", therefore does only imply food and not drink. (M-W: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/edibles)