# Catch-all adjective for "edible" and/or "drinkable"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, synonyms

This is similar to [another post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49358/collective-word-for-food-and-drink#:%7E:text=15%20Answers&text=Sustenance%20refers%20to%20food%20and%20drink.&text=Victuals%20might%20at%20a%20pinch,drink%20as%20well%20as%20food.&text=%22Victuals%22%20is%20the%20correct%20word,of%20the%20word%20%22vittles%22.), but for adjectives instead of nouns.

I'm looking for an adjective that describes objects that are *safely* edible and drinkable, and are meant for consumption (e.g. something that is explicitly called "non-toxic" would not be covered).

"They're advertising <adj> supplies for camping."

Comment: I think it's ***the same*** as the earlier question. All the (noun) suggestions there can be used as "noun adjuncts" before "supplies" (and some can be used to form adjectives, though not necessarily idiomatic for this context).

Comment: It strikes me as a very odd example, because I don't think anyone would ever say "they're advertising edible supplies", or "drinkable supplies", or "<long adjective> supplies", they would say food and/or drink. But I guess people want to say all kinds of things.

Answer (score 0):

After some thought, the word "[consumable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/consumable)" comes to mind. It can be used either as an adjective or a noun.

Comment: Consumable doesn't really fit: as your link shows, it means something which is consumed or is capable of being consumed, but that includes things like fuel which are consumed when they are burnt.

Answer (score 0):

**Ingestible** means suitable for eating or drinking: Merriam-Webster says: of the verb "[to take in for or as if for digestion](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ingestible)", so ingestible as an adjective would mean *capable of being taken in as for digestion*.

It's not a very common or nice word, it's a bit too close to "indigestible" which might be confusing, and "ingestible supplies" is longer than "food and drink" so I'd recommend the latter. Nonetheless, it does have the meaning required.